# Only match if the 13SL exists in the line

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this piece of text that is inside a huge string:

linha[0] = '13SL         1R$          226.185,81                            ';

I need make th following e regex only works if the 13SL exists, but i need confirm the 13SL and
still catch everything between the ''... Now the regex is only matching what is between
the 13SL and the final ';

```
linha\[0]\s=\s'13SL(.*)';
```

http://regexr.com/3ck3j

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've placed your capture on the wrong spot, try this:

```
linha\[0]\s=\s'(13SL.*)';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
linha\[0]\s=\s'(13SL.*?)';

                      ^^
```

Besides capturing group,use `non greedy regex` or else it will extend upto last `'`